# Download gmail emails before a certain date to MS Outlook through IMAP

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, gmail-imap

I am currently using MS Outlook to connect to my gmail account through IMAP. I would like to download all gmail emails before the year 2015.

Can this be done?

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2019. Thank you.

Comment: A simple question is: Why?

Comment: If the goal is simply to save space on gmail you can search for `Larger:10M` (to find messages over 10MB in size) in the gmail search field and remove the mails you no longer need.

Answer (score 0):

Are your emails before 2015 not downloaded in the outlook client?

If so, considering the impact of the limit on the number of emails in the folder, it is recommended that you could log in to Gmail web mail and go to the Gmail settings page and change the Folder Size Limits section to: **Do not limit the number of messages in an IMAP folder (default)**.
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.